# How do I use a regular expression to match any string, but at least 3 characters?

Tags: regex

I am not a regex expert, but my request is simple: I need to match any string that has at least 3 or more characters that are matching.

So for instance, we have the string "hello world" and matching it with the following:

```
"he" => false // only 2 characters
"hel" => true // 3 characters match found
```

Comment: 3 or more characters from anywhere in the string or specific position? If literally "any three characters" is a match, isn't any string with a length of 3 or more characters a match? Just take the string length...

Comment: What about `hwd`, true or false?

Comment: To answerers: Variants of `.{3,}` is not what OP wants.

Answer (score 61):

This is python regex, but it probably works in other languages that implement it, too.

I guess it depends on what you consider a character to be.  If it's letters, numbers, and underscores:

```
\w{3,}
```

if just letters and digits:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,}
```

Python also has a regex method to return all matches from a string.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'\w{3,}', 'This is a long string, yes it is.')
['This', 'long', 'string', 'yes']
```

Comment: Yeah, I totally answered a different question than the OP was asking.  After reading Paxdiablo's solution it made sense.

Comment: This however was totally my question, so thank you for answering!

Answer (score 14):

Try this .{3,}    this will match any characher except new line (\n)

Comment: This answer is language agnostic

Answer (score 4):

If you want to match starting from the beginning of the word, use:

```
\b\w{3,}
```

\b: word boundary

\w: word character

{3,}: three or more times for the word character

Answer (score 4):

I tried find similiar as topic first post.

For my needs I find this

http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/217-how-to-match-whole-words-with-a-regular-expression/

```
"\b[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}\b"
```

3 char words only
"iokldöajf **asd** alkjwnkmd **asd**  **kja**  wwda da **aij** ednm <.jkakla "

Comment: See the comment below the question: "To answerers: Variants of .{3,} is not what OP wants."

Comment: But it doesn't answer the question anyway.  It's the search expression itself that has has to be at least three characters long. For example, if the user is typing in a search dialog, it shouldn't start highlighting matches until at least three characters have been entered.  The OP didn't say anything about whole words.

Answer (score 1):

You could try with simple 3 dots. refer to the code in perl below

> $a =~ m /.../ #where $a is your string

Answer (score 0):

For .NET usage:

\p{L}{3,}