# php regex at least 3 characters match?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

any ideas how to modify this regex:

```
([A-Z]{3}[0-9][0-9A-Z-\/]*)
```

so it matches from at least characters {3} (3 and more) not just {3} ?

cheers,

/Marcin

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590286/regular-expression-to-match-any-string-but-at-least-3-characters

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All you need is a comma:

```
([A-Z]{3,}[0-9][0-9A-Z-\/]*)
```