# How can I match lines with only 1 character in them?

Tags: regex

So i am cleaning up a .txt in Notepad++ getting rid of some crap data by using the Find and Replace. here is an example of what i have

```
3
http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/Wkan7AqnIpQ/hqdefault.jpg


https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/903847782a309d54b4cc065a5db01674?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG
3

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKWlS.jpg?s=128&g=1
https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/69e84fb0e0943636b7de859b6db5eaf4?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG
6
```

NOTE: underneath 6 is an empty line

What i want to do is find all the lines which only have a single character in them since they wont be valid urls. my own research lead me to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2590286/1028804) which is where i started using this

```
\w{1,}
```

however this was getting me every group of numbers and letters (each group separated by symbols). so i thought to add `\r\n` since the lines i want removed would always contain the newline characters. it limited the results but it was getting me the end of every line which at text.

i also tried `[0-9]{1,}\r\n` because at this time i am only expecting numbers on single lines and this reduces the results more but the .imgur link is bring picked up as well because of the 1 at the end.

So what else can i do so i can get rid the lines which only have 1 character in them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html), (`^` start), (`$` end) in order to determine if there is only a single character on that line [(example)](https://regex101.com/r/lO9kD7/1):

```
^\w$
```

You may also need the `m` multi-line flag in order to match the start/end of each line rather than the start/end of the entire string.

Comment: And if these 'single characters' are always numbers, `\d` can be used as character class.

Comment: Replace the regex with nothing to remove the lines you don't want.

Comment: Also, `^\S{1}$` could be useful if the you want to match any line that has one character that is not whitespace.